# Devise and Warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, permissions

I've been using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for a little while, and I've realized it's built on something else called [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) that handles authentication. What does Devise offer me outside of Warden, because I was considering removing devise and just using Warden.

Comment: I have no freakin' idea what you're asking.

Comment: Devise extends Warden which involves something called a "Rack" or some such. I'm not a Rubyist so beyond that I've no idea. I think he's wondering if base Warden is find without Devise or if Devise brings something critical to the table.

Answer (score 6):

Warden is the kernel of rack-middleware authentication. Devise is a complete authentication system for rails applications.

Let's take an analogy: Warden is like the Linux kernel, while Devise is like a complete Linux-based operating system such as Debian or Fedora. Or another: Warden is like the engine, while Devise is like the rest of the car.

For more details, please read the respective manuals *that you linked to in your question*.